# Doctrine sorting Numbers with attached letters

Tags: php, database, sorting, symfony, doctrine

I've got a db-field (integer) with numbers from 8000 to 12000.

My doctrine looks like this:

```
public function findAllOrderedByNumber()
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->orderBy('a.nr', 'ASC')
        ;
    }
```

Now I want to attach letters to some numbers (like `10510a`).
I've changed the field type from `integer` to `varchar` but now the sorting output is: 9999,9998...,8000,10000,10001...

How can I keep letters in my numbers and still get the "right" (in terms of numbers) sorting order?

Thanks

Comment: Create virtual field containing the int only and sort by that first and the varchar next.

Comment: Actually you can do the two steps in one:
addSelect('ABS(a.nr) AS HIDDEN foo');
And then: orderBy('foo', 'DESC');